# Вызвать функцию GetSystemInfo через ассемблер

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, nasm

У меня есть функция GetSystemInfo которая встроена в winapi (sysinfoapi.h), как мне её вызвать?

А затем поместить ответ вызова функции в ячейку памяти.

C++:

```
void GetSystemInfo(
  LPSYSTEM_INFO lpSystemInfo
);
```

Официальная документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsysteminfo

Это всё что я смог найти.

Comment: Вообще, зависит от битности исполняемого файла. Если 32-битный, то push адреса на блок памяти под структуру [`SYSTEM_INFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-system_info) и `call [GetSystemInfo]`. Если 64-битный, то немного сложнее (так не помню, нужно гуглить).

Comment: Для win api удобнее использовать fasm или masm - с обоими ассемблерами идут подключаемые файлы для упрощения вызовов функций win api.

Comment: про push знаю (аргументы), и про call (вызвать функцию), но задал вопрос потому что не знаю что такое lpSystemInfo, и как его пихнуть в GetSystemInfo.

Comment: @LEON, то есть не знаете? :) Даже по вашей ссылке прямым текстом сказано: указатель на структуру SYSTEM_INFO

Comment: то есть просто "extern SYSTEM_INFO", а затем через push как-то добавить его, или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Нужно выделить где-то блок памяти (в стеке, в секции данных или через malloc) количеством байт как эта структура, дальше через push передать адрес этого блока памяти. После вызова там должны появиться данные. extern это вообще про другое.

Comment: можете пожалуйста просто дать ответ на этот вопрос, я ничего не понял)

Comment: Я могу дать ответ для fasm. Если такой вариант подойдет, то ок.

Comment: ну попробуйте, может пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **DISCLAIMER:**
>
> Нет никакого смысла писать этот код на ассемблере, все то же самое
> намного проще было бы написать на Си (в конце пример).

Насколько возможно минимальный пример на fasm, результат - 32-битный консольный exe файл:

```
format PE CONSOLE
entry start

include 'win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable

  start:
    invoke GetSystemInfo, system_info

    ; dword перед [system_info.wProcessorArchitecture] нужно из-за того что это 2-байтовое поле (word),
    ; его нельзя просто так передать с помощью push.
    ; dword здесь приводит к тому, что по адресу поля читается 4 байта вместо 2.
    ; Но это корректно работает только потому, что после этого поля идет зарезервированное пустое 2-байтовое поле
    ; (если бы было не пустое, вывелось бы неправильное значение)
    cinvoke printf, format_string, dword [system_info.wProcessorArchitecture], [system_info.dwPageSize]
    invoke getch ; ожидание нажатия клавиши перед завершением, можно и без этого, если запускаете из командной строки
    invoke ExitProcess,0

section '.data' data readable writeable

system_info SYSTEM_INFO

format_string:
    db 'wProcessorArchitecture: %d', 0x0d, 0x0a
    db 'dwPageSize: %d', 0x0d, 0x0a, 0

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel32, 'KERNEL32.DLL',\
    msvcrt, 'MSVCRT.DLL'

include 'api/kernel32.inc'

import msvcrt,\
    printf,'printf',\
    getch,'_getch'

section '.reloc' fixups data readable discardable
```

Тут для примера вывод значений только первых двух полей - `wProcessorArchitecture` и `dwPageSize`.

В 32-битной версии выводит:

```
wProcessorArchitecture: 0
dwPageSize: 4096
```

0 соответствует `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL`, см. описание структуры [`SYSTEM_INFO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-system_info)

Если изменить в коде PE на PE64 и `include 'win32a.inc'` на `include 'win64a.inc'`, получится 64-битный экзешник, вывод будет такой:

```
wProcessorArchitecture: 9
dwPageSize: 4096
```

9 соответствует `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64`.

"Магическая" строка `system_info SYSTEM_INFO` - это макрос, который при компиляции разворачивается в набор полей соответствующей структуры, например для 32-битного экзешника (взято из файла `fasm/include/equates/kernel32.inc`):

```
struct SYSTEM_INFO
  wProcessorArchitecture      dw ?
  wReserved           dw ?
  dwPageSize              dd ?
  lpMinimumApplicationAddress dd ?
  lpMaximumApplicationAddress dd ?
  dwActiveProcessorMask       dd ?
  dwNumberOfProcessors        dd ?
  dwProcessorType         dd ?
  dwAllocationGranularity     dd ?
  wProcessorLevel         dw ?
  wProcessorRevision          dw ?
ends
```

Для 64-битной версии все то же самое, только размеры полей-указателей (те, что начинаются на `lp`) другие - 64-битные (`dq`) вместо 32-битных (`dd`).

---

Также нужно сказать, что `invoke`, `cinvoke` - это макросы, которые при компиляции превращаются в разный код в зависимости от подключенного в начале программы файла - `win32a.inc` или `win64a.inc`.

Для 32-битной версии `invoke` превращается в 0 или более `push`, и `call` в конце - соглашение `stdcall`. Для `cinvoke` порядок `push` противоположный, и после `call` еще выравнивается стек на размер переданных через `push` параметров - соглашение `cdecl` (используется для функций с переменным числом параметров, как у того же `printf`). См. [Соглашения о вызовах, используемые на x86 при 32-битной адресации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85,_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_x86_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_32-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Для 64-битной версии все несколько сложнее, можете для ознакомления посмотреть здесь: [Соглашение о вызовах для 64-разрядных систем](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019)

---

P.S. более-менее эквивалентный код на Си:

```
include <windows.h>
include <stdio.h>

SYSTEM_INFO system_info;

int main() {
    GetSystemInfo(&system_info);
    printf("wProcessorArchitecture: %d\n"
           "dwPageSize: %d\n",
           system_info.wProcessorArchitecture,
           system_info.dwPageSize);
    // Тут мог быть вызов getch();, но эта функция не входит в стандарт, поэтому не добавляю
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться.

Comment: @LEON, хорошо. Если нужно будет что-то пояснить - пишите.